# Python script to write list of dict with multiple values to multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby

I have a list of dicts as shown below. I wish to write the dicts to multiple excel or csv files depending on the keys. if the keys are the same they should be in one file.

my_list_of_dicts:

```
[{'john': ['0', '100']}, {'john': ['4', '101']}, {'john': ['0', '102']}, {'mary': ['2', '100']}, {'mary': ['5', '101']}, {'mary': ['4', '102']}, {'mary': ['1', '103']}, {'sam': ['4', '100']}, {'sam': ['3', '101']}, {'sam': ['12', '102']}, {'paul': ['2', '100']}, {'hay': ['2', '100']}, {'hay': ['1', '102']}, {'mercy': ['4', '101']}]
```

My code so far:

```
x = []
i = 0
for ii, line in enumerate(my_list_of_dicts):
    with open("out_%s.csv" % i, 'w+') as f:
        if line.keys() not in x:
            x.append(line.keys())
            i += 1
            pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=line, orient='index').to_csv(f, header=False)
        else:
            pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=line, orient='index').to_csv(f, header=False)
```

Result:

I am getting the desired number of files but not the content.

Expectation:

I expect to get files corresponding to each key i.e (john, mary, sam, jay, paul, hay, and mercy) with the below content. Using john as example:

```
john, 0, 100 
john, 4, 101
john, 0, 102
```

I am not sure how to proceed or if I even need enumerate. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean to use i instead of ii in your for loop?

Comment: No that is why I said I was not sure if using enumerate was the right idea cos the ii was not used

Comment: Normally if you aren’t going to use something like that you would use _

Comment: Okay now I know. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better idea is to aggregate your data into a single dataframe and then iterate a `groupby` object:

```
# construct dataframe from list of dictionaries
df = pd.DataFrame([[k, *v] for dct in L for k, v in dct.items()])
df[[1, 2]] = df[[1, 2]].apply(pd.to_numeric)

# iterate groupby object and export to separate CSV files
for key, df_key in df.groupby(0):
    df_key.to_csv(f'{key}.csv', index=False, header=False)
```